# 'System.TypeInitializationException' being thrown on previously working code

Tags: c#, event-log

**My code worked fine previously, but now when I run it; it throws up this exception:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
>   occurred in Debug Chamber.exe  Additional information: The type
>   initializer for 'varBank' threw an exception.

What's even weirder is that I have changed nothing except for adding this class:

```
public class readParameters
{
    public static void readLog(int start, int end)
    {
        for (int x = start; x < end; x++)
        {

        }
    }
    public static void nextLine()
    {
        string[,] logArr = new string[4, 5];
    }
}
```

The line in question is highlighted in the block below

---

```
/// </data bank>
public class varBank
{
    public static string logInput { get; set; }

    public static PathType FilePath { get; private set; }

    public static EventLogReader evl = new EventLogReader(logInput, FilePath);

    public static EventRecord bsnRecord = evl.ReadEvent();
}
/// </data bank>

namespace EventLogInfoReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Log Location: ");
```

> ```
>           varBank.logInput = Console.ReadLine();
> ```

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Read Parameters: ");
            int i = 1;
            while (++i > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Property: ");
                string CommandInput = Console.ReadLine();
                getInfo.callInfo(CommandInput);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One of your static fields failed to initialize... Debug startup of the application to find out which... Also I bet it is reading files...

Answer (score 0):

That exception means an exception was thrown from a static constructor or field initializer.  I suspect it's in the initializer for `evl`, since it's referencing static properties that do not have initial values set (they will be `null`).

I would move that code to a static constructor so you can do better error handling and/or logging.  Both `evl` and `bsnRecord` have static initializers thatr are vulnerable to run-time exceptions and should not go unchecked.

I also question why you have static properties that's initialized using *other* static properties.  What do you expect to happen if client code sets the `FilePath` property?